# Regular expressions: how to find any word with the form [(non quotation mark)whatever(non quotation mark)]

Tags: regex

I want to find any word where it has a square bracke, then no simple quotation mark, then whatever, then no simple quotation mark and then the closed square  bracke.

For example, look this words:

```
['car in the mountain']
[sister in law]
['dog']
```

The result must show me:

```
[sister in law]
```

Exists any regular expression can do it that?

Comment: yes it exists, please show your own attempt in question

Comment: @anubhava is only for search in Visual Studio Code files, is not for code

Comment: So `[sister in law's]` would be valid along with `[a]`?

Comment: What about `[sisters']`? possessive plural

Comment: Or `['til]`: short for "until"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus right, for example, [abc] is also valid or [ab'] or ['ab] is also valid

Comment: But those last 2 cases is very rare, so they don't matter for this example

Comment: Regex is a fickle beast. Far too often people will add countless follow-up scenarios which they didn't think of which invalidates peoples' answers. It's better to think of these things now instead of later because it tends to annoy people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
\[(?!'[^\]]*'])[^\]]*]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYoaDD/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\[`: Match starting `[`
- `(?!'[^\]]*'])`: Negative lookahead to fail the match when we have a `'` next to `[` and just before `]`
- `[^\]]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `]`
- `]`: Match closing `]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\[[^'].*`
It matches the opening square bracket and any character immediately after it except `'`

Comment: This fails for `['til]`

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if it fail for cases like ['hello] or [hello'], so this answer is very useful